# reboot vs shutdown -r now for restarting Linux

Tags: linux

I normally use `reboot` to restart my Linux box, but a friend said that I should use `shutdown -r now` instead. Is there any difference?

Looking at the man pages tells me something about run levels, but I'm hoping for an answer in simple English that a relatively inexperienced Linux user can understand.

Comment: Related: [What is the difference between reboot , init 6 and shutdown -r now?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/64280/22339)

Answer (score 7):

Many Unix systems have `reboot` perform an *instant* reboot -- no syncing, no umounting, nothing. It's just like hitting the reset button.

Your friend is trying to save you hours of fscking, or worse, if you ever wish to reboot one of those systems.

Comment: For example, this is the behavior for reboot on Mac OS X, so already we're talking about the majority of deployed end-user UNIX systems. As per Shakedown's answer, this likely varies between different *NIX types.

Answer (score 4):

There are likely slight differences in the functionality offered, but they can both be used to achieve the same thing. In fact, here's what the manual page for `reboot` says:

> When called with --force or when in runlevel 0 or 6, this tool  invokes
>          the reboot(2) system call itself and directly reboots the system.  Otherwise this simply invokes the **shutdown**(8) tool  with  the  appropriate
>          arguments.

Also, it appears that the RUN-LEVEL info for both operations is the same. Judging from the manual pages of both reboot and shutdown, it looks like shutdown provides a bit more lower-level functionality, and reboot is a higher-level tool that uses shutdown.